# bounded sequence in dual space of $L_p$

Tags: functional-analysis, lp-spaces

Fix $p \in \mathbb{N}$, given $(f_k)_k \subset L_p(\mathbb{R}^n)$. For every $T \in L_p(\mathbb{R}^n)^*$ (dual space), $(|T(f_k)|)_k< \infty$. Show that $(f_k)_k$ is also bounded in $L_p(\mathbb{R}^n)$.

I have to show that, $\int_X |f_k|^p dx <\infty$. Unfortunaly, I don't know how to start, so I am very thankful for hints.

Greetings.

Comment: The natural inclusion of a Banach space in its bidual is an isometry.  Apply the uniform boundedness principle to conclude.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am not aware of the buniform boundedness principle. Isn't there a other  way, without going in its bidual? I thought via contradiction.

Comment: Doing it without applying the Uniform Boundeness Principle to the bidual would, I think, be the same as proving the principle for the space $(L_p(\mathbb R^n)^*$.

Comment: I try to imagine how the dual space looks. Let's say we have $l_p$ instead of $L_P$. Then its dual would be $l_q$ such that $\frac{1}{p}+\frac{1}{q}=1$ with $x \in l_p$, the linear functionals would be $ \sum_{j \in \mathbb{N}} x(j)y(j)  $ $y \in l_q$.

Comment: in the fashion of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/781833/the-principle-of-uniform-boundedness-and-lp-space

Comment: Casn't we just argue that since  the map $f\mapsto f^{**}$ where $f^{**}(T)=T(f)$ is an isometry, we must have $\|f_k\|_p=\|f_k^{**}\|=\sup_{\|T\|=1}|f_k^{**}(T)|=\sup_{\|T\|=1}|T(f_k)|<\infty$

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This seems very elegant. I guess it is a well known theorem that $f^{**}(T)=T(f)$ is an isometry?